# PHP Detect a 5 card straight within an array of 7 cards

Tags: php, function

I have this function which can detect a *straight* in Poker if the hand is exactly 5 cards but not so sure how to find one if it's among 7 cards.

```
  public function straight($hand) {
    sort($hand);
    if ($hand == range($hand[0], $hand[count($hand)-1])) {
        $this->hand_name = 'straight';
     }
  }
```

Let's assume that the array is already a string of numbers only. So these would be the desired results.

```
2 3 5 7 12 7 4 - no straight

2 3 5 6 12 7 4 - straight

7 8 9 10 11 11 11 - straight

2 4 5 6 14 10 9 - no straight
```

Let's not worry about the Ace being 1 or 14 problem for now, I can get around that but the function should allow for duplicates since that's how cards are.

Also note I only need to determine if there is a five card straight or not....I don't need to get the cards involved or compare them with another etc.

EDIT: I should also point note that it should of course detect a 5 card straight within less cards like 6 cards or 5, but not 4 obviously.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply modify your existing function to iterate over the groups of 5 cards (created using [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)) within the 7 after you have sorted:

```
function straight($hand) {
    sort($hand);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($hand) - 5; $i++) {
        $subhand = array_slice($hand, $i, 5);
        if ($subhand == range($subhand[0], $subhand[count($subhand)-1])) {
            echo implode(',' , $hand) . " => straight\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
straight(array(2, 3, 5, 7, 12, 7, 4));
straight(array(2, 3, 5, 6, 12, 7, 4));
straight(array(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11));
straight(array(2, 4, 5, 6, 14, 10, 9));
straight(array(2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 4));
straight(array(3, 5, 6, 12, 7, 4));
straight(array(7, 8, 9, 10, 11));
straight(array(2, 4, 5, 6, 3));
```

Output:

```
2,3,4,5,6,7,12 => straight 
7,8,9,10,11,11,11 => straight
3,4,5,6,7,12 => straight
7,8,9,10,11 => straight 
2,3,4,5,6 => straight
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SeFSo)

Comment: @treyBake I learn something new about them (there are so many of them!) on this site almost every day.

Comment: Ok but would that work if there were only 5 or 6 cards and not the full 7? I missed that out of my question accidentally.

Comment: Yeah that's perfect, I tested it and it works with everything. Nice work.

Comment: Actually I noticed it's not 100% perfect. It's perfect in that it always detects a straight or not, which is what my question asked for, but if I want to detect what level of straight it is, working from the bottom up does not detect the best straight. For example, if the cards are 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 then it would detect a 6 high straight. It would be better if it started from the top and worked down, this way it would detect the 8 high straight first. You could update your answer to `for ($i = count($hand) - 5; $i >= 0; $i--)`

Comment: @Hasen indeed. This function as is effectively only returns a boolean value as to whether there was a straight or not. If you want to return the best straight in the hand then starting at the end and working back would be the way to go. Then you could simply return the value of `$subhand[4]` to indicate the top card of the straight (and perhaps return 0/false at the end of the function to indicate that no straight was found)